# BASH Space in filename IsSUE

Tags: bash, solaris

I have a bash script which executes a Java Command and passes the space delimited String as an argument. Lets say the java class is "HelloWorld" and the required argument is passed as 
"-environment WIN XP". So the lines in my script are :

```
        env = WIN XP
        arg=" -environment $env"
        javaCmd="java -Xmx2000m foo.bar.HelloWorld $arg"
        $javaCmd
```

My HelloWorld  class gets only the partial argument -environment WIN and throws an error because it is expecting -environment WIN XP as a whole with spaces. What are the ways in which I can make sure the entire String is treated as once without getting split at the whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

[I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

You need to use an array to preserve which elements contain whitespace:

```
    env="WIN XP"
    javaCmd=( java -Xmx2000m foo.bar.HelloWorld -environment "$env" )
    "${javaCmd[@]}"
```

All the quotes above are necessary

Answer (score 2):

THere should be no space between `=` and the name when assigning a variable. I would propose you use a different name than `env` for a variable.  Also the variable `arg` isn't really necessary here. You can directly incorporate that in `javaCmd`.

```
env="WIN XP" 
javaCmd="java -Xmx2000m foo.bar.HelloWorld -environment $env"
$javaCmd
```

Comment: Thanks chcikegg. I had put in simple case. Real case is that the variable env is a file name like test sample ${NUMBER}.xlsx, where NUMBER is passed as the script argument. So if I pass 2004, env gets set as test sample 2004.xlsx, but the issue still remains. My Java code still gets the value as test and not test sample 2004.xlsx.

Comment: `-environment` still sees a single argument, `WIN`, with `XP` treated as a separate argument to `java`. You simply cannot do nested embedded strings like this in `bash` without using an array.

Comment: thanks Chepner. Can you demonstrate the usage of array to handle the space issue.